# ggplot2 legend entries change from posixct to integer when using scale_color_gradientn

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, legend

I'd like to make a path plot in ggplot2, with the path based on a timeseries, and a continuous color aesthetic to show this path. The legend should associate the color with timeseries. The legend is nice when the color aesthetic is defined in the original call to ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)

times <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 02:00:00"),
                    to = as.POSIXct("2017-10-03 12:34:00"), 
                    by = "min")
values <- rnorm(length(times))

dat <- data.frame(times = times, 
                  values1 = sin(values[order(values)]), 
                  values2 = cos(values[order(-values)]))

ggplot(dat, aes(values1, values2, color=times)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image: Legend is good!]

However, I want to use a different color scale than the default. When using `scale_color_gradientn`, or `scale_color_continuous`, the legend entries seem to get converted from POSIXct to integers:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = values1, y = values2, color = times)) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(4))
```

[image: Legend not so good!!]

**How do I either (1) specify a custom color scale in the first plot, or (2) maintain POSIXct legend entries in the 2nd plot?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `scale_colour_datetime()` which is used by default, all it does is:

```
scale_colour_continuous(trans = "time")
```

So adding `trans = "time"` to your desired colour scale works:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(values1, values2, color=times)) +
    geom_path() +
    scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(4), trans = "time")
```

Output:

[image]